# How to open a file in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I want to actually **open it** not just read it.
I tried to do something like this:

```
x = open("filename", "r")
abc = x.read()
x.close()
```

The above code just read the file, it did not actually open the file.
The file is a "bat" file

Comment: Is your file an image or a PDF? Specify the file type.

Comment: `x = open("/path/to/filename.extension", "r")` would just open it with nothing else

Comment: Define "open". What, exactly, does that mean to you? "a Notepad window appears with the contents of the file, and the user can interact with it"? Something else?

Comment: If it's a `.bat`, do you mean *execute*, rather than *open*?

Comment: someone already answered me so tnx for your intentions and by the way how can i close it and delete it after??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`open` creates a stream of data associated with the file. It does not initiate a file viewing software.

```
os.startfile('path/to/file.ext') # opens file in respective program
```

Comment: tnx it worked, and by the way how can i close it and delete it after??

Comment: @roncohen What operating system are you on?

Comment: Firstly, please mark as answer with the check mark on the side.

Comment: Secondly, what program is used to open this file? What is the file extension?

Comment: Its a bat fille but for anther time what is the what is the difference??

Comment: Because the only way to stop the program is to kill the process of the opened file. For example, if you opened a text file you would need to kill notepad. What does the batch file open?

Comment: the bat file just rans a simple code, i just wanted to cobain a simple addon (that i have made) to my main project

Comment: Anyway, you should use [`taskill`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx) because you are on windows. Just pass in your  command into `os.system`. For example, `os.system('taskkill /im python.exe')`.

Comment: like this: os.system("taskkill") ?

Comment: Your on the right track. Just add the name of the process you wish to kill.

Answer (score 0):

You must invoke `filename.bat`

Also, the explicit `.read()` can be removed in `abc = x.read()`.

Comment: Have you actually tried, what you are suggesting here? How exactly does `abc = x` open or read the file? I suggest, you edit or delete this comment.