# Open URL from Python 2.7

Tags: python, html, macos, python-2.7, urllib2

From Python 2.7 (Anaconda) on OS X, how do I open a URL in a web browser?
The following syntax:

```
import urllib2
urllib2.urlopen("https://www.google.com/")
```

prints my running .py file to a browser window.  I've tried many examples online with the same effect.

Comment: That code when run with Python will not put your running python source file to a browser window, no. It'll return a response object instead.

Comment: That's what it *is* doing, instead of opening the google in a browser.

Comment: This simply queries a request to the server at the given URL.

Comment: @anon0909: then your question is *unclear*. If you want to control your browser from Python, use the [`webbrowser` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Reminds me of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171745/how-to-open-a-file-in-python-3) question. People don't really understand what open means, huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com') # open a passed URL string using default browser
```

Comment: This gives the same result.

Comment: the script that calls this functions appears in a new tab in my default browser.  It does not open google.com.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your code, console, and browser.

Comment: @anon0909: it sounds as if you associated `.py` with something to open in your browser.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Exactly, you can't click to run on Mac OS. Use Terminal.

Comment: I don't know what the problem was before, but this works now.